# ¿Cómo interpretar "[animal con] Cuatro patas y cinco pies"?

Tags: definiciones, significado, animales

La foto de abajo es de un texto de un libro sobre dinosaurios para niños. En una de las solapas (es uno de esos libros de abrir solapas para revelar texto) la descripción dice:

[image]

> El diplodocus pesaba el triple que un macho de elefante africano. Era un herbívoro con **cuatro patas y cinco pies**, igual que los elefantes.

Leyéndosela a mi hijo, me quedé sin saber cómo interpretar esa frase. ¿"**Cuatro** patas pero **cinco** pies"?

Acudir al diccionario no me sirvió de mucho. Una [pata](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S71hGRM%7CS72dH32) es (o debería ser), en este contexto, "**Pie** y pierna de los animales." y el [pie](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SwyZKJX) es "En los animales, parte análoga al pie humano" que a su vez es la "Extremidad de cada uno de los dos miembros inferiores del cuerpo", o sea, la pierna para los humanos y la pata para los animales.

No consigo lograr que esa frase tenga sentido, pues cada *pata* debería tener su correspondiente *pie* y solo uno. No sé si el quid de la cuestión está en los posibles significados de pie y/o pata, algo relacionado con la biología, o si es otra cosa, pero desde luego no entiendo la frase.

¿Puede alguien explicar el sentido de "era un animal con cuatro patas y cinco pies"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creo que quieren decir "... y cinco dedos":

#### Elefante

[image: Elefante]

#### Diplodocus

[image: Diplodocus]

Comment: [Elefantepedia](http://www.elefantepedia.com/la-pata-del-elefante/) confirma que los elefantes tiene cinco dedos en cada pata, así que es razonable pensar que "pies" es una errata del texto.